# Is there a better way to implement a simple Factory with two conditions?

Tags: java, if-statement, design-patterns, factory

I have the following class structure:

```
MyClass
  FirstClass
    FirstClassVersion1
    FirstClassVersion2
  SecondClass
    SecondClassVersion1
    SecondClassVersion2
```

At a certain point i need a reference of MyClass according with class number and class version, so i created a simple factory. But my factory is a little complex as follow:

```
public class MyClassFactory {

    public static MyClass createMyClass(int classNumber, int classVersion) throws Exception {
        if (classNumber == 1) {
            if (classVersion == 1) {
                return new FirstClassVersion1();
            } else if (classVersion == 2) {
                return new FirstClassVersion2();
            }
        } else if (classNumber == 2) {
            if (classVersion == 1) {
                return new SecondClassVersion1();
            } else if (classVersion == 2) {
                return new SecondClassVersion2();
            }
        }

        throw new Exception("...");
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another idea:

```
public class MyClassFactory {

    private MyClassFactory instance = new MyClassFactory();

    private MyClassFactory() {}

    public MyClassFactory getInstance() { return instance; }

    public MyClass create(Class clazz) throws Exception {
       return clazz.newInstance();
    }
}
```

Embellish this as needed (e.g. stronger type checks using generics).

Your way requires that you modify the factory every time you extend the class.  That can't scale.